# WiFiManager API in Android Q, R

Tags: android, wifi, android-10.0

I am writing a sample application which is scanning for available wifis and connects to them programmatically

For that propose, I'm using [WiFiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION), but recently Google deprecated most of the methods that are allowing to scan for WiFis and Connect to them programmatically.  And yes it seems logical from Google's side to not allow anyone to try to connect to any WiFi programmatically.
But my questions will be following

- Is there still a way to Scan for available WiFi-s
- Is there a way to connect to a Public WiFi
- Is there a way to connect to a Private WiFi programmatically, or if no if there is a way to suggest user connect to a private WiFi, so user can enter a password

In the new API I found a way how I can suggest user connect to the WiFi

```
wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(listOf(WifiNetworkSuggestion
                   .Builder()
                   .setSsid("testWiFi")
                   .setWpa2Passphrase("test1234")
                   .build()))
```

but this is working really unpredictable, the first time when I run my all and call this method, on Android Q it's showing a notification and on Android R it's showing dialog asking the user if he allows connecting to the WiFi-s when app somehow connects to the WiFi but after that calling the same function for another WiFis does nothing and app is not showing any more ant notification or dialog (it this a bug? )

also I tried `requestNetwoerk` method

```
val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier
        .Builder()
        .setSsid("testWiFi")
        .setBssid(MacAddress.fromString("testWiFiMac"))
        .build()

val request = NetworkRequest
        .Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
        .build()

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
```

but in this case, it's not very clear if it is possible to connect to password-protected WiFi, and if yes how to do that.

So if there are some examples or explanations, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

even if start scan is deprecated Google still recommends to use it.

The three steps here are:

1. Register a broadcast receiver for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.
2. Request a scan using WifiManager.startScan()
3. Get the scan results with WifiManager.getScanResults(). Note that if you are using these scan results before receiving the results from the broadcast, these results might be a bit older from previous scans.

Sample code might be look like this:

```
val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false)
    if (success) {
      scanSuccess()
    } else {
      scanFailure()
    }
  }
}

val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter)

val success = wifiManager.startScan()
if (!success) {
  // scan failure handling
  scanFailure()
}

....

private fun scanSuccess() {
  val results = wifiManager.scanResults
  ... use new scan results ...
}

private fun scanFailure() {
  // handle failure: new scan did NOT succeed
  // consider using old scan results: these are the OLD results!
  val results = wifiManager.scanResults
  ... potentially use older scan results ...
}
```

For devices running on Android Q or higher, the only method to properly to connect to a public or private wifi which is not intended as a peer to peer network is to use the NetworkSuggestionAPI as you already showed in your question.

The reason why you sometimes don't see the network suggestion is the following:
"If the user uses the Wi-Fi picker to explicitly disconnect from one of the network suggestions when connected to it, then that network is ignored for 24 hours. During this period, that network will not be considered for auto-connection, even if the app removes and re-adds the network suggestion corresponding to the network.", cited from the Google documentation website.

For more information about the wifi scanning look at the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#kotlin

More information about the WifiNetworkSuggestion API can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest